# ValidForm Builder - How to add custom functionality to addButton() object

Tags: javascript, php, validform

I'm using [ValidForm Builder](http://validformbuilder.org) to build my forms in PHP.

I have 2 custom buttons on a ValidForm as shown in the code below. Both buttons submit the form in a manner that causes form validation to occur.

I am looking for the syntax to cause the Cancel button to either go back a page, similar to the way the browser back button works like this `onclick="window.history.go(-1)"` or to cause the back button to bypass form validation.

**Source Code:**

```
  // SUBMIT BUTTONS
  $objGroup = $objForm->addButton('Insert User Group', array('fieldname' => 'action'));
  $objGroup = $objForm->addButton('Cancel', array('fieldname' => 'cancel'));
  // END USER GROUP UPDATE SECTION

  // FORM DATA HANDLER
  if ($objForm->isSubmitted() && $objForm->isValid()) {
    require_once(CORE_SQL . 'users_userGroups.php');
    if (strpos(strtolower($_POST['action']), 'insert') !== false) insertUserGroup();
    elseif (strpos(strtolower($_POST['action']), 'update') !== false) updateUserGroup($_POST['userGroupID']);
    elseif (strpos(strtolower($_POST['action']), 'delete') !== false) deleteUserGroup($_POST['userGroupID']);
    header('Location: ' . PATH_USERS . 'userGroups.html');
    exit;
  }
  else {
    $strOutput = $objForm->toHtml();
  }
```

**Screen Shot of Cancel Button onClick Behavior can be seen this [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bytqhoir_Tt5NmpDbnkybEpBekk/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add this meta array:

#### In your PHP code:

```
array(
    "fieldname" => "cancel",
    "fieldid" => "form-cancel-button"
);
```

You can then use Javascript to handle this buttons' actions. Since you've already included jQuery for use with ValidForm Builder, you can do something similar like this:

#### In your Javascript code:

```
$("#form-cancel-button")
    .off("click") // remove ValidForm's default handlers
    .on("click", function () {
        window.history.go(-1);
        return false;
    });
```

That should do the trick. But in my opinion, a cancel button shouldn't 'go back'. A cancel button should just clear the form and stay on the current page.

#### ValidForm Builder syntax

By the way, I see you're using $_POST to fetch data from your posted form. That's a big no-go. ValidForm Builder enables you to validate and sanitize user input before using it in the rest of your application (like SQL queries). The syntax to extract a value from ValidForm Builder (when submitted and validated) is this:

```
$strFieldValue = $objForm->getValidField("fieldname")->getValue();
```

Thisway, you know the user input has been validated by ValidForm Builder and is safe to use.

Comment: `But in my opinion, a cancel button shouldn't 'go back'. A cancel button should just clear the form and stay on the current page.` I completely agree. But I could not think of any other way to make it happen because I was struggling with the VFB syntax. I plan to test your answer momentarily. Thanks @RobinvanBaalen